# JBoss AS7 - Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

Always when I deploy my project (jsf) I get the following error on my JBoss AS7. On JBoss 6 everything worked fine. What can be reasons for that error message? Do you have any idea how I can solve that?

**JBoss AS7-Console**

```
21:25:17,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myproject.war"
21:25:17,662 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."seminarpla
ner.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to proce
ss phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myproject.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final
.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2
.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class at.uhs.myproject.util.HibernateTransactionFilter w
ith ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-serve
r-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)

        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final
.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar
:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-serve
r-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session from [Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module Load
er]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        ... 15 more

21:25:17,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myproject.war" was rolled bac
k with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.servic
e.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"sem
inarplaner.war\""}}
21:25:17,756 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myproject.war in 48ms
21:25:17,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.Star
tException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "seminarplane
r.war"

21:25:17,764 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was
 rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject.war\".
POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myproject.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: Do you have a hibernate library in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory? If so, try removing it.

Comment: no, I've no hibernate libary in my `WEB-INF/lib` but I've the following jars in it: richfaces-core, richfaces-componets, sac, cssparser.

Comment: Do you have anything annotated with @PersistenceUnit or @PersistenceContext? See the implicit modules for more details, https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments.

Comment: I have nothing annotated with `@PersistenceUnit` or `@PersistenceContext`. I don't think that I've a problem with annotations. I get this error after deploying my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've the answer to my question. I had to edit the `jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file and add the following content (add a datasource):

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDatasource" pool-name="myDatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase</connection-url>
                <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>false</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>myUser</user-name>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```