# Maven deploy does not find external project dependency

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly, ear

I am trying to deploy an EAR on a wildfly local server (specifically keycloak 7.0.0), and it returns me an error in one of the providers (only this error returns me):

> Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"

And the jar-module has this structure:

[jar-module structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbIPI.png)

in the LoginStorageProviderFactory it has a import from LoginStorageProvier and in this last class has an import from a User class that it's in a external project, also mine.

If I move this User class into the jar-module, the error disappears and it works everything well; but my target it is to have modulated the project with the implementation of User in the other project and the EAR project separated.

So, I think the error is causing because a dependency is missing, Maven can't solve it and doesn't report that error, only Maven can't solve a class because dependencies are missing.

I have my pom.xml (ear project parent of ear-module and jar-module):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
    <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>ear-module</module>
        <module>jar-module</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
        <jboss-logging.version>3.4.1.Final</jboss-logging.version>
        <keycloak.version>7.0.0</keycloak.version>

        <jboss.home>target/keycloak</jboss.home>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- [THE OTHER PROJECT] -->
            <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
            <artifactId>focusoc</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>7</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>public/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>public/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>LICENSE.txt</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>dependencies.txt</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anyone knows if something is missing?

**Edit:**

I include here  the full error trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project login-provider-focusoc-module: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found"}}}}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project login-provider-focusoc-module: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found"}}}}
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"login-provider-focusoc-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found"}}}}
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute (AbstractDeployment.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :login-provider-focusoc-module
```

Also the ear-module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc</artifactId>
        <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
            <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc-module</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeLibInApplicationXml>true</includeLibInApplicationXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the jar-module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc</artifactId>
        <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>login-provider-focusoc-module</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss-logging.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- demonstrates usage of custom dependencies in an ear -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gcs.fds</groupId>
            <artifactId>focusoc</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: There should be a stack trace in the servers logs which would be helpful to see.

Comment: I just added it in the main body

Comment: Is `gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory` in your JAR?

Comment: Yes, is included in one of the packages

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can be answered here: [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)

I think now your EAR project depends on JAR project. Therefore, in pom.xml of ear, you should declare jar project as dependency. Then you can have multiple options to build your projects by maven:

1. 'mvn clean install' in parent directory: it will install ear and jar to your local
2. 'mvn clean install' in jar project then 'mvn clean install' in ear project. The output will be the same as 1.
3. If you want install your ear project and related dependencies in the future by just 1 command, run 'mvn install -pl ear -am' in parent directory.

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace on here and provide the pom for sub modules? May be we can investigate further

Comment: I just added it in the main body

Comment: It seems like it failed at deploy step - which is already passed the compile step. I guess that now the error comes from the wildfly configuration. Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652783/jboss-as7-failed-to-process-phase-post-module-of-deployment

Comment: Nothing, I have added the new parameters of datasource and nothing. The only thing that I could saw it's the difference that I found between having an User class inside the jar-module that works perfectly, and I have it in a external project (focusoc) this error comes.

Comment: So far what i can found is here: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/wildfly/plugin/deployment/AbstractDeployment.java . The error throw at line 117. I do not familiar with Wildfly deployment process so I cannot help you further on this. Maybe you can checkout this repo and go through the code to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to find a solution with the imports... beacuse I think that the problem is that it is not importing the external project.